# Saving a Layer Mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, mask

How can I save the following mask as a PNG image ?

I pressed Alt + Right-click on the mask to get the following image but I don't know how to export it

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of adding an Adobe Photoshop tag to decrease the pushback you're likely to get given you don't ID the software in the text of the question; of course it's clear from the image, but the tag and/or text in title appear on the main questions list, whereas the image doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's as simple as selecting all (Cntrl-A Win | Cmd-A Mac), copying that contents (Cntrl-C Win | Cmd-C Mac) and exiting mask preview, adding a new layer and pasting the copied contents into that new layer (Cntrl-V Win | Cmd-V Mac) - you then can export it as a .png as you would any other contents of a typical layer.

Comment: You dont need the new layer creation step it will just create one when you paste.

Answer (score 0):

The way it works to me:

Select the layer mask.

Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>A</kbd> .

Then press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>C</kbd> .

Create a new Layer and press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>V</kbd> .

Now you can export it to png, jpg, etc.